# Zabbix Aggregate items to monitor VPN connectivity

Tags: foreach, vpn, monitor, zabbix

I´m monitoring lot of servers, but once the VPN is down Zabbix causes multiple alarms for each hosts.

My solution was to create a calculated item, using foreach to get "0" if all the hosts in the hostgroup are down. In that case I would have one alert saying that connection to X group is down and not 200 alerts for each host like now.

I tried with these items, but not successfully:

`count(last_foreach(/*/agent.ping?[group="HOSTGROUP-A"]))`

`nodata(last_foreach(/*/agent.ping?[group="HOSTGROUP-A"]))`

I thought this would work, but if I stop the zabbix agent in all the hosts from this Hostgroup, it still returns X, instead of 0.

I think it just counts the agent.ping items assigned to each host, but not the real output from this item. Maybe because the agent.ping return 1 or "error" if no connection is done.

Also tried with "nodata", but seems to be not supported together with the _foreach

Tried with count/sum.
Other operators give erros.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [trigger dependencies](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/en/manual/config/triggers/dependencies).

> Sometimes the availability of one host depends on another. A server
> that is behind a router will become unreachable if the router goes
> down. With triggers configured for both, you might get notifications
> about two hosts down - while only the router was the guilty party
> While Zabbix does not support dependencies between hosts directly,
> they may be defined with another, more flexible method - trigger
> dependencies. A trigger may have one or more triggers it depends on.
> [..]
> So in our simple example we open the server trigger configuration form
> and set that it depends on the respective trigger of the router. With
> such dependency, the server trigger will not change its state as long
> as the trigger it depends on is in the 'PROBLEM' state - and thus no
> dependent actions will be taken and no notifications sent.

You can set dependancies by hand, or through a script that uses the [trigger api](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/en/manual/api/reference/trigger/update)